# What is the GNU operating system and the Unix shell?

Tags: gnu

I have seen the GNU labelled as an operating system. The Unix shell, as I understand it, is related to Linux. I would like an explanation of what they are, exactly how both of them are used and how to get them on my computer, which is currently running Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin.

Answer (score 2):

[GNU](http://www.gnu.org/) is originally Richard Stallman's project to implement free unix alternative. All modern Linux distributions are based on GNU project toolset. In Stallman's opinion, they should be called as GNU/Linux, instead of just Linux. For example official [Debian FAQ](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/) does this.

With Ubuntu, you already have GNU operating system. As of Unix shell, Linux is (almost completely) POSIX compatible, and similar to Unix shell. Obviously, you can select different shells (for example, bash or zsh) in your Ubuntu installation.